# I didnt branch off of master, instead branched off of a branch

Tags: git

I have 3 branches, Master, B1, and B2.

Is it possible to rebase B2 back off of master, isntead of B1.

I did a checkout on Master and was working in B1 to resolve things.
I did a second checkout, and thought it was off of Master, and resolved more bugs.

Now I am in a scenario of Code Reviews and i see something like this.
Master -> B1 -> B2

and Both B1 and B2 are up for code review, so B2 contains B1s commits.

Is it possible to rebase B2 so it is off of Master such that it doesnt see B1's commit history?

I was not sure how to reset where it forked from or the best course of action to resolve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do this with rebase:

```
git checkout B2
git rebase --onto master B1
```

This will rebase the commits from `B2` up to, but not including, the commit at the tip of `B1` onto `master`.

Comment: This did it.  I did notice though that there were some hiccups, so I needed then follow it up with:  `git push --force` otherwise it would throw an error to push because i was behind.  When i first attempted without a force, I pulled and pushed and it looks like it didnt do what I wanted.  When I forced it, it looked like it wiped out the changes

Comment: @Fallenreaper Yes, whenever you do a rebase, you must do `git push -f` in order to update the remote repo to be like your local repo. Note that this can cause problems if anyone else has pulled the original version of the branch before a rebase. Their history will be contain the original commits and if they do work and commit on that branch, all hell will break loose when they also `git push`. This is a general concern that applies to all commands which change the history of a branch.

Comment: Or in one command, `git rebase --onto master B1 B2`, regardless on which branch you're currently on.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice, if you can add the "make sure you force push" to the answer, that would be wonderful

Comment: @Fallenreaper In the context of the question, I'm not sure that talking about `git push` in the answer makes any sense because your OP doesn't mention anything about a remote repo. IMO, that topic belongs in a separate Q&A.

Comment: Ah, ok.  That makes sense I guess.